# Chrome Padding Issue On Paragraph Text

Tags: jquery, firefox, google-chrome, size, padding

I'm a little new to the web development scene and I was having a very persistent problem with Chrome that I can't quite seem to figure out.

I'm using the [Compact News Previewer](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/10/03/compact-news-previewer/) to show new entries to the database. You'll notice that if you view the demo in Firefox everything fits nice and snug, but in Chrome the paragraphs within the left-hand column get truncated. I'm having this same issue in my own implementation as seen below (Note: My implementation is a little different from the demo):
[image: Paragraph text gets truncated in chrome]

You can see this issue for yourself if you go to [this website](http://lists.cogmation.com).

What I've tried:

1. [CSS Reset](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/reset/) - yields no different results.

**Edit**

I'm using Chrome V18.0.1025.151, going to try a system update on Ubuntu so I'll check in tomorrow and see if this fixes the issue.

**Edit 2**
Evidently I'm using the latest version of Google Chrome, might be a problem with this version. But if nobody else can see the issue then perhaps it's a non-issue...

***Edit 3***
Found out that I was using Chromium instead of Chrome, I didn't realize there was a difference. I installed Chrome 7 instead but I'm getting the same problem as with Chromium. Also suddenly neither of these browsers are able to display some of my jpg images? C̶h̶r̶o̶m̶e̶ ̶m̶u̶s̶t̶ ̶b̶e̶ ̶i̶n̶c̶r̶e̶d̶i̶b̶l̶y̶ ̶b̶u̶g̶g̶y̶ ̶o̶n̶ ̶U̶b̶u̶n̶t̶u̶!̶ <-- Human-error!

Comment: looks fine for me. Chrome/Win7

Comment: Your image doesn't illustrate the point clearly. Can you refine it? Clearly mark with some sort of red highlight what's wrong.

Comment: Updated the image. I'm using Chrome on Ubuntu but when I saw a colleague open my website on windows 7 I saw the same problem.

Comment: Working fine in Chrome 19.0.1084.56

Comment: Can you check the value of computed `line-height` property on that buggy element in Chrome Developer Tools?

Comment: line-height is normal, padding and margins are 0, the font is 12px the same as it is in Firefox.

Comment: looks fine to me too in Chrome, but what you could do is remove the top padding on ".cn_list p" in the css and it should look fine, imo it looks better without those 2px in padding-top

Comment: Do you have the font that is in your css on your Ubuntu machine? If not, does the fallback font have similar size/line height?

Comment: FWIW, I can reproduce in Chrome 19.0.1084.56 m on Win 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like the issue is due to Chrome's default `line-height` and the fonts that you are using on the page. Myriad Pro and Trebuchet MS seem to have very wide leading when used with Chrome's default; sans-serif is fine. Since `.cn_list p` has a fixed height and `overflow:hidden` set, the huge `line-height` Chrome gives these fonts pushes the text out of the box, cutting it off.

You have a couple of options:

- Specify a `line-height` value in your `.cn_list p` rule or in a rule for a parent element, like `body` to cascade it down. (Something like `1` or `1em` will tighten it up, but YMMV.)
- Remove the fixed height and hidden overflow, which would probably break your design since it would ruin the grid.

Adding a `line-height` should do the trick for you there, though.

Projects like HTML5Boilerplate [always set a default `line-height`](https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/master/css/main.css#L76) for just this reason.

Comment: Chrome seems unresponsive to any of my css changes. I tried incognito mode + clearing content caches but still nothing happens. Even if I set every p element to display:none it still persists the old stylehseet. Also, I imagine manipulating the line-height would make the FireFox version look strange, is there a line-height that only affects Chrome?

Comment: Doh! I was looking at the production version of my website instead of the dev version. Yeah, manipulating the line-height fixed it in Chrome. But is there a way to apply this line-height change to chrome only so it doesn't affect the Firefox version?

Comment: Never-mind, setting a default line-height gets the styling for Firefox and Google Chrome in sync. Thanks for the help!